# shutil.move() - error message that the destination file does not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, shutil

I have the following code to sort CSV files into a directory structure similar to the WAV files the CSV files were created from:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import shutil

WAV_FILES_PATH = 'g:\\wav_files\\test007\\'
CSV_FILES_PATH = 'g:\\csv_files\\test007\\'

wav_files_path = os.walk(WAV_FILES_PATH)
csv_files_path = os.walk(CSV_FILES_PATH)

# I'm only interested in CSV files in the root for CSV_FILES_PATH
(csv_root, _, csv_files) = csv_files_path.next()

print('Running ...')
for root, subs, files in wav_files_path:
    for file_ in files:
        if file_.endswith('wav'):
            for csv_file in csv_files:
                if(file_.split('.')[0] in csv_file):
                    src = os.path.join(csv_root, csv_file)
                    dst = os.path.join(csv_root, root.replace(WAV_FILES_PATH, ''), csv_file)
                    print('Moving "%s" to "%s" ...' % (src, dst))
                    shutil.move(src, dst)
```

There are subfolders in WAV_FILES_PATH that contains the WAV files, e.g.

```
g:\wav_files\test007\run001\
g:\wav_files\test007\run002\
```

As the CSV files are located unordered in `g:\csv_files\test007`, I want to clone the directory structure and move the CSV files to their correct folder. In the end, I want to have e.g. `g:\csv_files\test007\run001\` to contain the CSV corresponding to the WAV files in`g:\wav_files\test007\run001\`.

The problem is that the `shutil.move()` command gives me an `IOError [Errnor 2]` complaing that the DESTINATION does not exist. This confuses me, as I have write access to the destination and shutil.move() claims that the target directories don't have to exist.

Am I missing something here?

The print() functions prints out the src and dst correctly.

This is the error output:

```
[...]
C:\Python27\lib\shutil.pyc in copyfile(src, dst)
     80                 raise SpecialFileError("`%s` is a named pipe" % fn)
     81 
     82     with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
---> 83         with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
     84             copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g:\\csv_files\\test007\\run001\\recording_at_20140920_083721.csv'
```

**INFO:** I added the error throwing part (the `with` blocks) directly to my code and it is NOT throwing an error. Now I'm copying the files myself and deleting them thereafter.

It appears to be a bug in how shutil.move() operates.

Comment: "shutil.move() claims that the target directories don't have to exist.". That's not how I read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move). It does say "The destination directory must not already exist.", but I'm taking that to hold in case `src` is a directory, not when it's a file.

Comment: I added `if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(dst)): os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dst))` before the `shutil.move()` command, which creates the directory at the correct place, but `shutil.move()` still fails claiming that the destination does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly modified your code and I think its generating the expected results.

```
#dst = os.path.join(csv_root, root.replace(WAV_FILES_PATH, ''), csv_file)
dst = os.path.join(csv_root, root.replace(WAV_FILES_PATH, '')) # Modified
```

I also added the following logic before executing shutil.move()

```
if not os.path.exists(dst):
    os.makedirs(dst)
```

Hope it will also work for you !!!